# Do Anonymous Functions Take Memory If Run In a loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

If I have 100 Objects in an array and for each object If I define an anonymous function for each object then will it take memory for 100 function(For onClick function), if yes then how to avoid it and if No then How JS manage it?

Code Example -

```
var a = [{a:1},{a:2},{a:3},...{a:100}];
var html = a.map((item, i) => (
      <div className={Styles.someCss} key={i}>
        <Component
         onClick={() => { this.someFunction(item) }}
        />
      </div>
    ));
```

Comment: @TheMaster, can you elaborate your answer(why?) because getting very diverse answer.

Comment: @TheMaster and what about onClick={()=>{}} function?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it will create 100 anonymous functions but that's not something one has to avoid. There is no other way of calling `this.someFunction` with an argument without creating a new function. You could call `bind`, as written in the [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html), but this creates a new object as well. So your code is totally fine.
(One hacky way around this would be to bind the `item` object stringified onto the DOM-Element via a data-tag, and then receiving it through `event.target`, but that's usually not the way-to-go.)

Comment: One more doubt that If we passing anonymous function to Pure Component then If parent component re-render then will Pure Component also re-render because of that anonymous function?

Comment: It will not because of the anonymous function, but if you put the mapping like this into render, the components will be initialized new everytime render is called.